# Why I can't use foreign key for more than one record?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, prisma

I am working on a backend project using nodeJS and Prisma.

Some context before I ask the question. I have an index entity, that is linked to a country and a risk type through foreign keys. So in this case I would want to be able to link a risk type to more than one index, and also I would like to link a country to more than one index. In this case, I would like to have an index called X that is linked to risk type A and country USA but also an index Z that is linked to risk type A and country DE, and finally, another index Y that is linked to risk type B and country USA.

The database definition was autogenerated by running the Prisma generation mechanism.

```
-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "risk_type" (
    "id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "parent_id" BIGINT,
    "category_id" BIGINT,
    "description" TEXT,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    CONSTRAINT "risk_type_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "country" (
    "id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    "code" CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    CONSTRAINT "country_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "index" (
    "id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT,
    "risk_type_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "country_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    CONSTRAINT "index_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

-- AddForeignKey
ALTER TABLE "index" ADD CONSTRAINT "index_risk_type_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("risk_type_id") REFERENCES "risk_type"("id") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;

-- AddForeignKey
ALTER TABLE "index" ADD CONSTRAINT "index_country_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("country_id") REFERENCES "country"("id") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;

-- CreateIndex
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_risk_type_id_key" ON "index"("risk_type_id");

-- CreateIndex
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_country_id_key" ON "index"("country_id");
```

The `schema.prisma` definition

```
model Index {
  id         BigInt        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String?
  riskTypeId BigInt        @unique @map("risk_type_id")
  riskType   RiskType      @relation(fields: [riskTypeId], references: [id])
  countryId  BigInt        @unique @map("country_id")
  country    Country       @relation(fields: [countryId], references: [id])
  createdAt  DateTime      @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamp(5)
  updatedAt  DateTime      @default(now()) @map("updated_at") @db.Timestamp(5)

  @@map("index")
}

model Country {
  id                 BigInt              @id @default(autoincrement())
  code               String              @unique @db.Char(3)
  name               String
  createdAt          DateTime            @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamp(5)
  updatedAt          DateTime            @default(now()) @map("updated_at") @db.Timestamp(5)
  index              Index?

  @@map("country")
}

model RiskType {
  id              BigInt     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name            String     @unique
  description     String?
  createdAt       DateTime   @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamp(5)
  updatedAt       DateTime   @default(now()) @map("updated_at") @db.Timestamp(5)
  index           Index?

  @@map("risk_type")
}
```

The question is fairly simple & stupid, why can't I insert foreign keys with the same value from order index records? For example, if I have index X with a foreign key '1' for risk_type_id, and I try to create an index Z with a foreign key '1' for risk_type_id I get the error below.

Prisma query:

```
ctx.prisma.index.create({
          data: {
            name: args.data.name,
            country: {
              connect: {
                id: args.data.country,
              },
            },
            riskType: {
              connect: {
                id: args.data.riskType,
              },
            },
          },
        });
```

results in this error:

> The change you are trying to make would violate the required relation 'IndexToRiskType' between the `Index` and `RiskType` models."

Also, if I run the SQL command in a SQL query console, I get:

SQL query:

```
insert into index (name, risk_type_id, country_id) 
values ('X', 1, 2)
```

Error:

> [23505] ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_risk_type_id_key" Detail: Key (risk_type_id)=(2) already exists.

The same error I when I try to insert a country foreign key already assigned to an index record.

Is there a flaw in the design that I don't see?

Is the relationship between Index and Risk Type wrong? (one-to-many atm)

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a problem with the FK, you made `"index"("risk_type_id")` unique.

Comment: a primary key is always unique, but you can add another index without uniqueness

Comment: Actually, that is the issue, I designed a one-to-one relationship by mistake, you both are right, the solution is to transform it into a one-to-many relationship. Thanks!